# Error with uploading a file in PHP

Tags: php

This is my code to upload files into Apachi folder (Got from w3schools). I am using **php-5.2.14**  and **Apachi_2.2.7** ,Windows server and the environment is working fine with all other PHP codes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    $target_dir = "C:/BackEnd/Apache/htdocs/mksysi/Pics/";
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
    ?>
```

Here with this code all the picture files I am trying to upload works with no problem into
**C:/BackEnd/Apache/htdocs/mksysi/Pics/**

(Here the target directory is created manually in the server.)

folder (Here the $target_dir).
But when ever I try to create another sub folder in the same target and upload a file it fails.

Error Output -**Sorry, there was an error uploading your file**

Eg- $target_dir = "C:/BackEnd/Apache/htdocs/mksysi/Pics/**Cars**";
Here I cant upload any picture files into **Cars**  folder.

Is there a limitation that I can write a path name ? Or whats wrong here ?
Please help me.

Comment: So where is the error you're talking about in the title? And can you show us how you make a directory? I don't see that in the code

Comment: you could perhaps try a little test to see if the target directory is writable. ie `if( is_writable( $target_dir ) ){/* ok */} else{ /* chmod(); */ }`?

Comment: Ali Alwash  >> I have updated the code .. Directory created manually

Comment: RamRaider >> Pics folder created manually with all rights.So do the rest